# Find linear transformation given a kernel and image

Tags: linear-algebra

Find a linear transformation $T: R^2 \rightarrow R^3$ where

> $Im(T) = sp \{(1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0)\} .$
>
> $Ker(T) = sp \{(0, 1)\}$

So, the first thing I did was to expand $Ker(T)$ to form a basis of $R^2$:

> $B = sp\{(0, 1), (1, 0)\}$

Next, I mapped the basis elements of $B$ to $Im(T)$:

> $T(B_1) = 0$ (since $B_1 \in Ker(T)$)
>
> $T(B_2) = (1, 0, 0)$

But since $B$ only has 2 elements, I can't map another element to $(0, 1, 0)$ (the last element in $Im(T)$).

Does that mean that this linear transformation doesn't exist?

Comment: Are you familiar with the rank-nullity theorem?

Comment: By Rank theorem, such application doesn't exist.

Comment: Is your question whether such a linear transformation does not exist (which has been answered) or whether you have given a valid proof of that?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: For a linear transformation $T:V\rightarrow W$, the rank-nullity theorem gives $\dim V= \dim kernel(T) + \dim image(T)$.
Now you can do book keeping: $2\ne 1+2$.

Answer (score 0):

Since that $$\dim(Ker(T))+\dim(Im(T))=\mathbb{R}^{2}$$
but, here $\dim(Im(T))=2$ and $\dim(Ker(T))=1$, so the rank-null theorem is not satisfied, so such a linear transformation does not exist.